# Flutter date range picker's in between color won't change

Tags: flutter, dart, color-scheme, daterangepicker, flutter-theme

I have a Flutter app that uses `showDateRangePicker` to pick a date range. When I pick a range, though, the color in between the picked dates is somehow cyan. I'm assuming it's one of the standard application colors since I haven't selected cyan anywhere myself, but I can't seem to find the right one so I can change it.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKac3.png)

Someone please help me out!

I've changed every color inside of `colorScheme` and it did not change the color of the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set inside your theme a datePickerTheme and overwrite the rangeSelectionBackgroundcolor:

```
theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(
            rangeSelectionBackgroundColor: Colors.red),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
```

Comment: This helped, thanks so much!
Because of your comment I discovered that I wrapped my picker in a Theme, which is why changing the main app theme didn't change anything. Super stupid, but thanks again because now I was able to change it!